# xsl, xml Line break inside for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have something like the following xml tree:

```
<block>
   <house>
      <room>
         <chair>number1</chair>
         <chair>number2</chair>
         <chair>number3</chair>
         <chair>number4</chair>
      </room>
      ...
   </house>
   ...
</block>
```

I am trying to return the results (number1,...number4) using the loop below.

```
<xsl:template match="g:block">
    <xsl:for-each select="g:house">
        <xsl:value-of select="g:room" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I get everything in a single row and I can't add line breaks somehow.

```
number1 number2 number3 number4
```

Is it possible to return each chair tag individually and then add /br to the output to get the following result?

```
number1
number2
number3
number4
```

I also tried to go deeper by adding another loop for each chair, but then I cannot extract the value of each chair tag.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
<xsl:template match="g:block">
    <xsl:for-each select="g:house/g:room/g:chair">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="g:room/string-join(g:chair, '&#10;')"/>
```

or the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="g:room/g:chair" separator="&#10;"/>
```

or the following (which works also in XSLT 1.0, but as you did not specify it, I assume you use XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="g:room/g:chair">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```